# Implementing a yield iterator of object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, continuations

I need a **true** iterator that will work like this:

```
var haystackObj = {
        'needle': 'abc',
        'prop2': {
                'prop1': 'def',
                'prop2': {
                        'needle': 'ghi',
                },
                'needle': 'jkl',
        },
};
var needleKey = 'needle';
var iterator = {
    next: function () {
            /* 
             * WHAT CODE GOES HERE? 
             * 
             * Should return the next property, recursively, with the name 
             * equal to needleKey, of haystackObj.
             *
             */
    }
};

var value = iterator.next();
console.log(value); // -> 'abc'
value = iterator.next();
console.log(value); // -> 'ghi'
value = iterator.next();
console.log(value); // -> 'jkl'
```

I think this would be trivial with a for(k in o) and first-class continuations, but JS doesn't have those.

EDIT: I can only scan haystackObj once.

EDIT2: I am *not* looking for "a way to iterate through object properties." I am looking for an [iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) of object properties. **That is a huge difference.** The problem is not as trivial as it may look at first glance.

Comment: What happened to "def"? Why is "ghi" outputted before "jkl"?

Comment: i guess "def" is ignored because its property name does not match needleKey `needle`

Comment: Did you try anything? It looks like you just want SO to make the code for you...

Comment: And btw: properties order is not certified in JS. Your requirements are impossible to fulfill.

Comment: further more you can use recursion and continuation passing style.

Comment: when did JS lose `for( var key in obj )` ??

Comment: What do you mean by "critical path"?

Comment: Wow people, so many negative votes. I have considered this problem for the past day. It's not as trivial as it looks! for(var key in obj) won't let me return one property at a time which is what an iterator does.

Comment: Try to freaking solve this problem before you downvote. I tried for(k in o) and several other methods, non of them satisfy the requirements of what I posted. I tried to put the problem as succinctly as possible.

Comment: most of you missed the point of the question didn't you. he want's "yield" semantics in JS. he want's to iterate a "tree" like structure and return control to the caller where the "key" is found, then continue iteration.

Comment: @Nick I really do not want to go back to conclusions... The people there were never nice to me....

Comment: @StanR. Then he should have used google and he would have found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037252/how-to-simulate-javascript-yield)...

Comment: @Neal If I had considered to search for 'yield in javascript' perhaps I would have.

Comment: @Neal, SO is for contributing ideas. Maybe Nick didn't realize that there is such a thing as "yield" and hence he couldn't have Googled for it. It's SO's job to recognize this and comment with a link, but it's apparent that its a circus over here.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: @xtal Thanks, missed a comma there.

Comment: @StanR. [This is relevant to you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166231/155556)

Comment: @Neal The simulated 'yield' [as linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037252/how-to-simulate-javascript-yield) won't work since the problem in this case is saving and then restoring the state of the generator.

Comment: @Nick, you should always explain why you're asking what you're asking.

Comment: @xtal I thought I did. =) In the original title I said a 'true iterator'. The question I posed asked for exactly that. And as far as I can tell atm, this problem can't be solved in JS. People just jumped to the conclusion that it was a stupid question.

Comment: @xtal Added another edit that will hopefully make that clear.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, but if you don't say *why* you want something, then that closes the door to the community offering alternative suggestions and perhaps even a completely different (and better) approach.

Comment: @xtal It would be very difficult for me to explain why and it would cloud a simple question (and a known concept! or so I thought) in details that are too specific to my needs. This code grabs a property and runs an NFA simulator on it, the NFA machine match tells the iterator when to return. I just stated the essence of the problem.

Comment: @Nick Your link just cites the entire Wikipedia article. You are still not being clear. For example JS already has internal iterators.

Comment: @xtal In other words, I thought that "Can I have an iterator?" in JavaScript is a perfectly valid, self contained question...

Comment: @xtal Well JS **doesn't** have iterators! That's the problem. It lets you iterate over object properties in a loop. There doesn't seem to be a way to consume properties one by one and preserve the state of that iteration. Changed the link to something more relavant.

Comment: @Nick. Okay that's a better explanation! You do it inside-out in JavaScript: iterate over a structure, pass control to a function, and then return from that function when you want to resume the iteration where you left off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this one for posterity.

In ECMAScript 6 we have a [yield](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3agenerators) statement. But lets say you're nuts and you'd like to use this feature *right now*. Compiled using the [traceur-compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) to your plain old JavaScript, we get the [following](http://goo.gl/9P8w4v).

#### Input:

```
var iterator = function* (object) {

        for(var key in object) {
                yield key;
                for( k of iterator(object[key]) ) {
                        yield k;
                }
        }
};

var o = {
        a: 10,
        b: 11,
        c: {
                ca: 12,
                cb: 13,
        },
        d: 14,
};

var res = [];
for( key of iterator(o) ) {
        res.push(key);
}

res;
```

#### Output

```
var $__generatorWrap = function(generator) {
        return $traceurRuntime.addIterator({
                next: function(x) {
                        switch (generator.GState) {
                                case 1:
                                        throw new Error('"next" on executing generator');
                                case 3:
                                        throw new Error('"next" on closed generator');
                                case 0:
                                        if (x !== undefined) {
                                        throw new TypeError('Sent value to newborn generator');
                                }
                                case 2:
                                        generator.GState = 1;
                                if (generator.moveNext(x, 0)) {
                                        generator.GState = 2;
                                        return {
                                                value: generator.current,
                                                done: false
                                        };
                                }
                                generator.GState = 3;
                                return {
                                        value: generator.yieldReturn,
                                        done: true
                                };
                        }
                },
                'throw': function(x) {
                        switch (generator.GState) {
                                case 1:
                                        throw new Error('"throw" on executing generator');
                                case 3:
                                        throw new Error('"throw" on closed generator');
                                case 0:
                                        generator.GState = 3;
                                throw x;
                                case 2:
                                        generator.GState = 1;
                                if (generator.moveNext(x, 1)) {
                                        generator.GState = 2;
                                        return {
                                                value: generator.current,
                                                done: false
                                        };
                                }
                                generator.GState = 3;
                                return {
                                        value: generator.yieldReturn,
                                        done: true
                                };
                        }
                }
        });
};
var iterator = function(object) {
        var $that = this;
        var $arguments = arguments;
        var $state = 20;
        var $storedException;
        var $finallyFallThrough;
        var $__0;
        var $__1;
        var $__2;
        var $__3;
        var $__4;
        var $__5;
        var key;
        var $G = {
                GState: 0,
                current: undefined,
                yieldReturn: undefined,
                innerFunction: function($yieldSent, $yieldAction) {
                        while (true) switch ($state) {
                                case 20:
                                        $__2 = [];
                                $state = 21;
                                break;
                                case 21:
                                        $__3 = object;
                                $state = 23;
                                break;
                                case 23:
                                        for (var $__4 in $__3) $__2.push($__4);
                                $state = 25;
                                break;
                                case 25:
                                        $__5 = 0;
                                $state = 17;
                                break;
                                case 17:
                                        if ($__5 < $__2.length) {
                                        $state = 12;
                                        break;
                                } else {
                                        $state = 19;
                                        break;
                                }
                                case 11:
                                        $__5++;
                                $state = 17;
                                break;
                                case 12:
                                        key = $__2[$__5];
                                $state = 13;
                                break;
                                case 13:
                                        if (!(key in $__3)) {
                                        $state = 11;
                                        break;
                                } else {
                                        $state = 15;
                                        break;
                                }
                                case 15:
                                        this.current = key;
                                $state = 1;
                                return true;
                                case 1:
                                        if ($yieldAction == 1) {
                                        $yieldAction = 0;
                                        throw $yieldSent;
                                }
                                $state = 3;
                                break;
                                case 3:
                                        $__0 = $traceurRuntime.getIterator(iterator(object[key]));
                                $state = 7;
                                break;
                                case 7:
                                        if (!($__1 = $__0.next()).done) {
                                        $state = 8;
                                        break;
                                } else {
                                        $state = 11;
                                        break;
                                }
                                case 8:
                                        k = $__1.value;
                                $state = 9;
                                break;
                                case 9:
                                        this.current = k;
                                $state = 5;
                                return true;
                                case 5:
                                        if ($yieldAction == 1) {
                                        $yieldAction = 0;
                                        throw $yieldSent;
                                }
                                $state = 7;
                                break;
                                case 19:
                                        $state = -2;
                                case -2:
                                        return false;
                                case -3:
                                        throw $storedException;
                                default:
                                        throw "traceur compiler bug: invalid state in state machine: " + $state;
                        }
                },
                moveNext: function($yieldSent, $yieldAction) {
                        while (true) try {
                                return this.innerFunction($yieldSent, $yieldAction);
                        } catch ($caughtException) {
                                $storedException = $caughtException;
                                switch ($state) {
                                        default:
                                                this.GState = 3;
                                        $state = -2;
                                        throw $storedException;
                                }
                        }
                }
        };
        return $__generatorWrap($G);
};
var o = {
        a: 10,
        b: 11,
        c: {
                ca: 12,
                cb: 13
        },
        d: 14
};
var res = [];
for (var $__1 = $traceurRuntime.getIterator(iterator(o)), $__0; !($__0 = $__1.next()).done;) {
        key = $__0.value;
        {
                res.push(key);
        }
}
res;
```

So `yield` statement in JavaScript, possible, but highly impractical.

## What I actually ended up using

#### Usage example:

```
var object = {...};
var callback = function (key, value) {

        // Do stuff...

        return traverse.CONTINUE; 
        // or return traverse.STOP if you want the iteration to stop
};

traverse(object, callback);
```

#### Implementation:

```
var traverse = (function () {

        var _traverse = function (object, callback) {

                var key, value, command;
                for( key in object ) {
                        value = object[key];

                        command = callback(key, value);
                        if( command === _traverse.STOP ) {
                                return _traverse.STOP;
                        }

                        command = _traverse(value, callback);
                        if( command === _traverse.STOP ) {
                                return _traverse.STOP;
                        }
                }
        };
        _traverse.CONTINUE = 1;
        _traverse.STOP = 2;

        return _traverse;
})();
```

Answer (score 7):

Properties order is not guaranteed in JS. Different engines behave differently. (Some engines based on alphabetical order, other based on last added order.)

Your requirements are thus impossible to fulfill.

If you just wanted an iterator without minding the order, you could take a look at this question/answers: [How to simulate JavaScript yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037252/how-to-simulate-javascript-yield)

This is what [the spec says](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4) about the properties order:

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified. Properties of the object being enumerated may be deleted during enumeration. If a property that has not yet been visited during enumeration is deleted, then it will not be visited. If new properties are added to the object being enumerated during enumeration, the newly added properties are not guaranteed to be visited in the active enumeration. A property name must not be visited more than once in any enumeration.

In reality however, you can expect a certain order from most browsers: [Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)

The only way I see to implement a fake generator (according to the fact that the order in reality suits you) would be to copy your object, and delete the scanned properties of the copy when needed. This'd mean you wouldn't rescan twice the same properties. Some code example:

```
var Iterator = function() {
    var copy = $.extend(haystackObj, true);
    // ^ using jQuery's extend for a quick function, but use w/e you want.
    // Anyway keep it in a closure. This copy will have its properties deleted
    // after each iteration.

    return {
        next: function next() {
            var found = false,
                needle;
            for (var prop in copy) {
                if (typeof copy[prop] === 'object') {
                    // Since next() doesn't take any argument...
                    // That's a bad solution. You should use an inner function
                    // to recurse. But I'm going to bed right now!
                    var copyCopy = $.extend(copy, true);
                    copy = copy[prop];
                    found = next();
                    copy = copyCopy;
                }

                else {
                    if (prop === needleKey) {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }

                if (found) {
                    needle = copy[prop];
                }

                // Delete the current property to simulate a real generator.
                delete copy[prop];

                if (found) {
                    return needle;
                }
            }
        }
    };
};

// Usage:
var iterator = Iterator();
iterator.next(); // "abc"
```

This code doesn't work (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCFeW/)), and I'm going to sleep. But you can see where it's going and how you could make something.

Comment: You win **the game**. Congratulations!

Comment: Great answer. This is specified in 12.6.4 of the spec

Comment: This is the only valid answer so far, why do I deserve negative votes for a perfectly valid question, I dont know.

Comment: the only semi-relevant answer, it seems that a lot of people here simply don't know that such a thing as generators exist.

Comment: Btw, I looked at the specs before I asked the question and came to the same conclusion. I also looked at Object.keys and friends. So I asked in case I missed some nooks and crannies of JS. Eh.

Comment: @Nick I updated the answer to add a relevant link. You might check it out and see if it fits your requirements.

Comment: @Nick Updated again to add a pseudo-solution.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine A clever solution. I will definitely be considering it. Thank you.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, the deep copy of the object is itself traversing the whole tree so this is not what the OP is looking for either.  see comments below my answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

Although Florian Margaine's answer points out that the order of the properties are dependent on the js engine, this solution works in chrome.  Took me a little bit of tweaking, but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/6zCkJ/3/:
Edited (this solution was done before OP said the tree can only be processed once)

```
var needleKey = 'needle';
var currIndex = 0;
var runningIndex = 0;
var getValueByIndex = function (obj) {
    var objToSearch = obj || haystackObj;
    for (var x in objToSearch) {
        if (x == needleKey) {

            if (runningIndex == currIndex)  {
                currIndex += 1;
                return objToSearch[x];
            }
            runningIndex += 1;
        } else if (typeof objToSearch[x] == 'object') {
            var found = getValueByIndex(objToSearch[x]);
            if (found) return found;
        }

    }
}

var iterator = {
    next: function () {
        runningIndex = 0;
        return getValueByIndex(0);
    }
};
```

Another approach which will only traverse the tree a single time is as follows http://jsfiddle.net/6zCkJ/6/.  The catch is that you must load the values array whenever the needle is updated:

```
var currIndex = 0;
var valuesArray = [];

var loadValues = function (obj) {
    var objToSearch = obj || haystackObj;
    for (var x in objToSearch) {
        if (x == needleKey) {
            valuesArray.push(objToSearch[x])
        } else if (typeof objToSearch[x] == 'object') {
            loadValues(objToSearch[x]);
        }
    }
}

loadValues();
console.log(valuesArray);
var iterator = {
    next: function () {
        return valuesArray[currIndex++];
    }
};
```

Edit: So far all answers posted here involve having to navigate the whole tree at least once or more which is not what the OP is looking for, including having to copy the object and remove properties as they are traversed. There is a solution though which involves marking the objects as they traversed with meta data which allows you to skip over the objects the next time they are encountered.  Using my first approach it would be rather trivial to add these optimizations and hopefully accomplish what the OP is requesting.

Alright, so I couldn't resist trying to get this to work.  Here is how I did it http://jsfiddle.net/6zCkJ/12/ .  You can see that I am storing the found objects in the foundObjects object, where the key is made up of the path to that object so you can do a quick lookup to see if it has already been recursed over.  The numFound is used to increment the running index properly.  I have not tested this heavily, but it should be a good start:

```
var Iterator = function () {
    var needleKey = 'needle';
    var currIndex = 0;
    var runningIndex = 0;
    var foundObjects = {};

    var getValueByIndex = function (obj,currentPath) {
        var objToSearch = obj || haystackObj;
        for (var x in objToSearch) {
            currentPath += x + '_';
            if (x == needleKey) {

                if (runningIndex == currIndex) {
                    currIndex += 1;
                    if (!foundObjects[currentPath]) {
                        foundObjects[currentPath] = {
                            numFound: 0,
                            finished: false
                        };
                    }
                    foundObjects[currentPath].numFound += 1;
                    return objToSearch[x];
                }
                runningIndex += 1;
            } else if (typeof objToSearch[x] == 'object') {
                if (foundObjects[currentPath] && foundObjects[currentPath].finished) {
                    runningIndex += foundObjects[currentPath].numFound;
                } else {
                    var found = getValueByIndex(objToSearch[x],currentPath);
                    if (found) {
                        return found;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!foundObjects[currentPath]) {
                foundObjects[currentPath] = {
                    numFound: 0,
                    finished: true
                };
            }
            foundObjects[currentPath].finished = true;
        }
    }

    this.next = function () {
        runningIndex = 0;

        return getValueByIndex(0,'');
    }
};
var iterator = new Iterator();
var value = iterator.next();
```

Comment: Nice one. It also works on Firefox and Opera. Can't test on IE unfortunately... However, you're scanning the `objToSearch` on every iteration. Not quite what OP wants.

Comment: I was not going for performance, but you are absolutely correct

Comment: Very nice. I would put all of this in a closure though.

Comment: After thinking about it, this looks nothing like an generator-like.

Comment: Yes, I've considered a similar solution. But as Florian stated I can only scan the object once, because this can potentially happen very often. I would need to write an essay on why I have such specific requirements, but they are what they are.

Comment: I even thought of getting a list of keys using Object.keys and then indexing into that. That would let me "jump" to the right point without having to scan up to the property every time. However, I also need the prototype chain to be resolved. Object.keys will only return hasOwn properties...

Comment: @Nick - no problem, I updated my answer to include another approach.  Let me know what you think

Comment: @JustinBicknell This is actually the solution that sent me searching. The problem is that its not an iterator. You pay the price of the entire scan up front and then you can consume one result at a time. In my application the object can be very large and you may only need the first five or so occurrences.

Comment: @Nick Is destructive iteration an option? As in, the original object fed to the iterator is modified every iteration. That way, you can excise all the content of the object up to your last match, which would be functionally identical to maintaining state.

Comment: @Asad This is similar to a solution that Florian added to his question in an edit. I can't modify the object in any way (my code doesn't own it), but _could_ make a copy before I start destroying properties.

Comment: @Asad I don't think thats necessary, unless you want it as an exercise. Florian has "almost working" code in his answer. The idea is the same.

Comment: @Nick - just a thought, but I'm not going to implement this, you could take my first approach and add a list of already traversed objects, which you can skip over for the next scan (not quite the same as deleting). That way you don't need to "copy" the whole obj in advance

Comment: @JustinBicknell I think this may be the best of both worlds so far. A sort of "fast forwarding" to the last property. You would need to keep a chain of these, since you are doing a deep search, but still doable. What I would need to measure is the cost of that for(k in o) up to first key that I'm actually interested in. I suspect copying the object is more expensive anyway...

Comment: @Nick - this is very similar to a data mining technique I learned in University, can't remember the name. But essentially when you have completed traversing a subtree, you "mark" it with meta data that can be used to skip over it the next scan.  In this case your meta data would have to contain the number of matches, and maybe the cost

Comment: @Nick I've updated my answer to reflect these ideas. Please let me know if that works out.

Comment: I can't see how you would iterate over an object starting from a specific property. Literally. The idea indeed seems to be the best of both worlds, but I just can't see how you would implement that.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine you're not starting off at a specific property, but you are pruning the tree in a sense. Because if you mark a property as "visited" then you do not have to recurse on that property again. you would effectively tag the property with meta information which you would use to answer to the parent. this is a technique commonly used in data mining algorithms

Comment: @JustinBicknell yes, but you're still iterating over it to see if it's a "marked property" or not. You sure don't have to recurse, but the iteration takes place.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine When skip over a very deep branch you have a huge performance gain. It's pretty easy to see that. Now its my bedtime

Comment: Indeed. Now on a practical point of view, how do you implement the marking? It's not like JS has metadata for objects like Clojure does. I'm genuinely interested.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - You bring up a good point.  Just adding a property to the object is not an option (just realized).  You would have to create a lookup object where the key is identifies the object itself (perhaps stringify the tree path to that property), and the value is the meta data.  Makes sense?

Comment: So you would almost duplicate the original object, including nesting? I'm not sure the trouble is worth it :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23992/discussion-between-justin-bicknell-and-florian-margaine)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Not quite, a single level obj with key value indexes

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Whether it's "worth it" depends on the performance gains

Comment: Alright, after having a chat, it indeed looks like the most performant solution. I'd just go for it if my solution turns out to be the bottleneck though, since it's quite a lot of trouble to set up.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine  - I was curious, so i attempted to get this to work - see my updated answer

Comment: @Nick - updated my answer again with an attempt at the latest idea

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand you correctly, and bearing in mind that this is not a 'true yield', and putting all the code where you seem to want it,

```
var iterator = {
    next: function () {
        /* 
        * WHAT CODE GOES HERE? 
        * 
        * Should return the next property, recursively, with the name 
        * equal to needleKey, of haystackObj.
        *
        */
        var values=[], findneedles;
        findneedles = function(o){
            var k;
            for(k in o){
                if(k === needleKey){
                    values.push(o[k]);
                }else if(typeof o[k] === 'object'){
                    findneedles(o[k]);
                }
            }
        };
        findneedles(haystackObj);
        this.next = function(){
            return values.shift();
        };
        return values.shift();
    }
};
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it is not an iterator. It scans the entire object up front, then uses those values. An iterator would only scan up to the next match and preserve state.

Comment: Yes, I already said that. You may as well just recurse over the structure and pass in a callback. But in the absence of any explanation of why this not acceptable ...

Comment: The reason this is not acceptable is because it is more computationally expensive than an iterator. Justin Bicknell has already posted an example of the approach you are taking here (see his second snippet). This does not answer the question.

Comment: Yp, this is exactly the same solution as Justin Bicknell's but you shift the results, he index into the array. Check my comments to his answer. The object can be very large and the entire point of the iterator is not to pay that search price up front.

Comment: Then just recurse and throw an exception when you're done. (And yeah; I hadn't seen his second answer when I wrote mine.)

Comment: @Nick Or do a breadth-first search and store references to unsearched child objects so you can resume iteration.

Comment: @xtal An iterator doesn't know when it's done, such is the nature of an iterator. =) As far as storing references to un-searched objects, see second part of Florians answer. I might do that.

Comment: I said when *you're* done, not the iterator. If you never know if you're done then you're going to have to scan the whole object anyway. And are you saying that you'd rather copy your entire enormous object rather than just store references to only the unvisited children?

Comment: I was referring to "throw an exception." It would be thrown from inside the iterator I presume. I'm saying the solutions are similar because to "know" what the unvisited children are you still have too loop through them (at each level of recursion.) And then store them, so you are still doing some copying.

Comment: @Nick. Throwing an exception: you only iterate as much as you need.
Breadth-first search: yes, you'd loop over one level at a time. I have no idea what your data is like so I can say whether this is performant or not. You have identified a bottleneck in your code and are measuring the speed of various solutions, right?