# Does Nashorn have an equivalent of "yield"?

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

The [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) keyword in JavaScript would be pretty handy for certain scripting tasks in Java 8's Nashorn engine.  Given the bleeding-edge-ness of `yield` (it's in ES6), it's probably not included in Nashorn, but I was curious if there's something similar available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate JavaScript yield?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037252/how-to-simulate-javascript-yield)

Comment: @BrandonBoone Thanks.  Related, but not the same -- this is largely a question about any non-standard extensions that might exist in Nashorn.